# Error "local filesystem access is forbidden" when triying to open a file databricks

Tags: python, scala, databricks

I am triying to open and read a file in Databricks (I have tried Scala and Python) but I get and error message `com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.scalakernel.SparkException: Cannot use com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.WorkspaceLocalFileSystem - local filesystem access is forbidden`.  I have tried using the Databricks FileStorage and the file in my PC.

This is the code:

```
%scala
var file_location ="file:/Workspace/Users/jmacevedo@hidden.com/dades_NO_CSV.20170101" //FileStorage  
//var file_location ="file:///C:/Users/Dell/Downloads/prueba/dades_NO_CSV.20170101"    //MyPC

var file_type = "csv"
var infer_schema = "false"
var first_row_is_header = "true"
var delimiter = ";"

var df = spark.read.format(file_type)
                    .option("inferSchema", infer_schema)
                    .option("header", first_row_is_header)
                    .option("sep", delimiter)
                    .load(file_location)

display(df)
```

The error in both cases is `com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.scalakernel.SparkException: Cannot use com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.WorkspaceLocalFileSystem - local filesystem access is forbidden`

The file doesn't have an extension, but if I open the format is csv. Example with header and two lines:

```
mm_aaaa;A0;A0_1;A0_7;A1;Residencia;CCAA;A14;A15;A16;A13_1;Factor
012017;2;20170102010177;2;2;13;13;8;4;6;4;91.152508218
012017;2;20170101000001;3;2;13;05;0;1;1;1;237.829703
```

Can you help me to open the file?.  Thanks

Then I will obtain from the first reg the mm_aaaa field.